# Python. Отложенное выполнение команды

Tags: python

```
            print('Cтоимость {} : '.format(Name), FileFifa_PayDay[Count])
            print('Национальность {} : '.format(Name), FileFifa_Nationality[Count])
            print(FileFifa_Image[Count])

            webbrowser.open(FileFifa_Image[Count])
```

Как сделать так , чтобы после print(FileFifa_Image[Count]) Python ждал некоторое время и переходил к ласт строчке?

Comment: Используйте функцию `sleep` из модуля `time`. `import time; time.sleep(sec)`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Можете сами, если хотите :) Я уже лёг спать и сижу с телефона, только завтра смогу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам может помочь функция [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) из модуля [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time).

***Пример:***

```py
from time import sleep


print('Cтоимость {} : '.format(Name), FileFifa_PayDay[Count])
print('Национальность {} : '.format(Name), FileFifa_Nationality[Count])
print(FileFifa_Image[Count])

sleep(5)  # 5 секунд ожидания

webbrowser.open(FileFifa_Image[Count])
```

---

<sub>Ответ был сделан на основе [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044277/python-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B?noredirect=1#comment1782128_1044277).</sub>